# Two sums from one list

Tags: python, list

I'd like to get the sums for two different values in a list. For example:

```
sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]
```

I'd like the output to be

```
13, 10
```

I could do it in a couple of different ways. Here's how I have it currently:

```
t1 = 0
t2 = 0
for item1, item2 in sample:
    t1 += item1
    t2 += item2
```

What would be a more Pythonic way to solve this?

Comment: Your alternative code doesn't actually work. `sample[0] == (1, 3)`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. You're right, I'll pull that example out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import izip
sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]
t1, t2 = map(sum, izip(*sample))
```

You can also use a list comprehension instead of `map`.

```
from itertools import izip
sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]
t1, t2 = [sum(t) for t in izip(*sample)]
```

And you can deal with more than two sums:

```
from itertools import izip
sample = [(1, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (8, 2, 1)]
sums = [sum(t) for t in izip(*sample)]
# sums == [13, 10, 3]
```

Comment: I think `itertools.izip` would be better, as `zip` still has to effectively double loop, which is something the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Third example looks like it'll be ideal in this case, thanks.

Comment: @SilasRay Thanks for pointing out `itertools.izip`. I've changed the examples to use it.

Answer (score 3):

A functoinal approach:

```
from operator import add
from functools import partial
sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]
result = reduce(partial(map, add), sample)
```

`result` will be the list `[13, 10]` after running this code.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]

r1 = 0
r2 = 0
for v in sample:
    r1, r2 = r1+v[0], r2+v[1]

print r1, r2
```

Although @FastTurtle's is cooler.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
sum([ x[0] for x in sample ]), sum([ x[1] for x in sample ])
```

Or for lists of unknown dimension:

```
map(lambda i: sum(x[i] for x in sample), range(len(sample[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this a lot (on big datasets), `numpy` will be helpful.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> sample = [(1,3), (4,5), (8,2)]
>>> sum(array(sample), axis=1)
array([ 4,  9, 10])
>>> sum(array(sample), axis=0)
array([13, 10])
```